# Python program displaying messages in different language than english

Tags: python-2.7, ctypes

I have written a simple python program in version 2.7.6 (32 bit). But when i display any message in a message box it comes in some weird language. The code is below

```
import Tkinter as tk
import win32com.client
import pythoncom
import ctypes
import sys
import glob
import sys
import os

MessageBox = ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW 

if __name__ == "__main__":
   MessageBox(None, "Hello", 'Window title',0)
```

and this is the output

[image: error output]

Comment: Is that your complete program?

Comment: this is a sample program i have written  just to show my problem

Comment: i am still not sure if it is the installer problem from where i have downloaded. the url i downloaded was from  http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7.6/

Comment: Its not an installer problem; you need to send a unicode string otherwise your normal string will be interpreted incorrectly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to send a unicode string; because you are using the unicode version of message box `MessageBoxW`, if you want to send normal ascii strings you need to use `MessgeBoxA`

```
ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA(None, 'Hello', 'Window title', 0) # or
ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(None, u'Hello', u'Window title', 0)
```

Comment: that did work. but i never had to do this when i had installed python 3.3. so is this different in 2.7 and 3.3?\

Comment: In Python3, [all strings are unicode objects](http://docs.python.org/3.3/howto/unicode.html#the-string-type) that's why it worked.

Comment: You're supposed to set the function pointer's `argtypes` to use `c_wchar_p`. Then you can call `ctypes.set_conversion_mode('utf-8', 'strict')`, or whatever encoding you prefer, to configure automatic conversion of byte strings to unicode. `set_conversion_mode` is only in 2.x ctypes. The default conversion mode is strict ASCII.

Comment: what's the "None" stand for?